# EventTrigger keydown give pressed key as command parameter

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to pass pressed key as command parameter in interraction?

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="???PressedKey???"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EventTrigger doesnt expose details about the event, it just registers to it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger(v=vs.100).aspx

You could instead write a Behavior, there you will control over which key etc:

https://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html

Comment: So in my viewModel i cannot get the event arg as parameter ?

Comment: You could have your Behavior execute a command in the viewmodel exactly the same view, only in the Behavior you will do your own registration to PreviewKeyDown, where you of course have the key pressed data.

Comment: Found working example here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01e87db7-72e6-43de-93e5-18b85d0089a2/attached-behaviour-why-does-keydownevent-not-fire?forum=wpf

Comment: I dont know what control you use it on, but perhaps it has its own handling of PreviewKeyDown.
In that case it wont be enough to += with EventHandler,
You will need to .AddHandler with 'Also Handled':

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Excuse me i forgot to update comment, now it's working by using previewKeyDown instead of keyDown. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

this code may solve your issue (It is for search with keypress by Binding) :

```
  <TextBox Height="20" Margin="-30,2,0,0" Name="searchText"  Text="{Binding SearchText}"  Width="254" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="EditValueChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SearchFieldCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=searchText, Path=Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                </TextBox>
```

To better understand this code should be familiar with PropertyChanged